# Format for cell that contains date and time to the millisecond

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a csv file that contains data in this format:

```
DateTime;Value
2016-03-09 08:28:24.000;1012.49
2016-03-09 08:28:24.333;1000.08
2016-03-09 08:28:24.666;1014.08
2016-03-09 08:28:24.999;1018.64
2016-03-09 08:28:25.333;999.7
```

If I open this file with excel, the milliseconds are cut off like this:
[image]

(The values under B are not the milliseconds. They are just corresponding values.)

I tried to format it as text, but this returns just one long number, like this:
[image]

I also tried a custom format as suggested in the answer to [StackOverflow / Display milliseconds in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3095407/display-milliseconds-in-excel)

But this does not disply the actual milliseconds, it just displays '000' where the right milliseconds should be.

How do I get excel to format my data right?

Comment: the issue is not only the number formatting, but also that Excel considers milliseconds to be in a different column. You either need to manage that during input to tell Excel that those should be in the same column. Or you need to add the two columns: `A2+TIME(0,0,B2/1000)`

Comment: When you are importing the csv file it is using `;` as a separator. You need to use another character, `,` for example.

Comment: Sorry, this is a missunderstanding. The number after the ';' is a seperate value. The ';' as the seperator is not the problem.